# Send JMS messages from Java EE application to Java SE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm not sure if the problem I have is rather a conceptual one or a technical one due to misconfiguration.

The goal is to send two way messages between a Java EE application hosted in an application container (specifically WildFly here) and a Java SE application running standalone all using standard JMS protocol and a topic. I though this shall be possible as long as they are both using same broker and same topic.

So I have an external Artemis instance running as the message broker and have successfully setup a producer and a consumer in separate beans on the Java EE application. They are both using same topic named "topic1". Messages sent by this producer is received successfully by the consumer bean.

Now I have setup another pair of consumer and producer in a Java EE application that runs **outside of any container** as an stand alone application. They are connecting to same broker, and are using same topic "topic1". Also messages sent by this producer is received by this consumer.

I was expecting when any of producers publishes a message, both consumers shall receive them. But nothing goes between these two apps. Neither the app inside container is receiving messages from standalone one, nor other way around. Am I making a conceptual mistake here or is something wrong with configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem and it was a rather misconfiguration. I was using the JNDI address of the topic on Java SE side, which was obviously a mistake, I should have instead used the topic name!